# Show suppressed errors not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am examining the Visual Studio 2010 Architectural Tools.
I created a Layer Diagram and created 3 Layers (UI - BIZ - DAL), i attached some classes to layers and generated dependencies. After i validated architecture i saw errors. Then, i right-click an error and select Suppress Error, so the error disappeared.

Now, i can't bring back the error. I click "Show Suppressed Errors"; but nothing happens.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way how i bring the errors back.
When you suppress an error, a file is generated by VS that name is DiagramName.diagramtype.suppress. 
You can delete any suppress that you want.

After that, you error come back :)